# Create FactoryGirl factory for Rails Model that Contains Callback that Queries DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have the following User model defined where after a new user is created, a default record is inserted into a join table between users and personality types (and yes...I know the default personality is corny):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :assign_default_personality_type

  has_many :personality_types, through: :personality_types_users
  has_many :personality_types_users, dependent: :destroy
  #using nested_forms gem
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :personality_types_users

  # When creating user, assign all to 'Loving' personality type by default
  def assign_default_personality_type
    if self.new_record?
      self.personality_types_attributes = [{ personality_type_id: PersonalityType.find_by_name('Loving').id }]
    end
  end
```

Here is my personality_type model

```
class PersonalityType < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :users, through: :personality_types_users
  has_many :personality_types
```

And I have a model for the join table class

```
class PersonalityTypesUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :personality_type
```

My problem is building the user factory through FactoryGirl.  Since I have a `before_create` callback linked to the `User`, when I try and build a new user through FactoryGirl, I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error: self.personality_types_attributes = [{ personality_type_id: PersonalityType.find_by_name('Loving').id }]

NoMethodError:
  undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

And I get it, when the user is built through FactoryGirl, there is no data in the test DB for the `Loving` personality type.  I'd *love* to get some help on this matter.  Here are my existing factories

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name { Faker::Name.first_name }
    last_name { Faker::Name.last_name }

  after(:build) do |em, evaluator|
    ...
  end


FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :personality_type do
    name { Faker::Lorem.characters(number: 6) }

  factory :loving_personality_type do
    name 'Loving'
  end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :personality_types_user do
    association :personality_type
    association :user
  end
```

In summary, my question is how do I get the `Loving` personality_type to exist before the user is created so that when the callback in the model is called, it has a personality ID to find?

What seems to sort of work is when I add the following FactoryGirl callback within the user model

```
after(:build) do |em, evaluator|
  loving_personality_type = PersonalityType.new(name: 'Loving')
  loving_personality_type.save
end
```

But this works for an isolated unit test.  When I run the entire spec model file, which has quite a few tests where the user is built and created across several tests, I get

```
Failure/Error: loving_personality_type.save

 ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique:
   PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_personality_types_on_name"
   DETAIL:  Key (name)=(Loving) already exists.
   : INSERT INTO "personality_types" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"
```

What I expect is that FactoryGirl is able to create a user with the association 'Loving' personality type. I do not want to go through the entire code base define the personality type in every RSpec file where a user is created.  All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `find_or_create_by` in your `after(:build)` block of the factory.

```
after(:build) do |em, evaluator|
   loving_personality_type = PersonalityType.find_or_create_by(name: 'Loving')
   loving_personality_type.save
end
```

This will essentially not create a new `PersonalityType` if there exists one in the database. It will however, return it's instance to the `loving_personality_type` variable.

This should solve your case IMO.

You can read more on it here: https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by